# speeding up a python3 rabin-karp implementation

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, rabin-karp

I'm trying to implement rabin-karp for a programming challenge.
my implementation is correct, but apparently it's too slow (the organizers have a time limit for each language, and my running time is double the limit! )

I use polynomial hashing, and use the rolling hash strategy.
Is there a way to speed up the algorithm?

Thanks!

(messy)python3 code follows:

```
P = 8597
X = 3613


def read_input():
    return (input().rstrip(), input().rstrip())

def print_occurrences(output):
    print(' '.join(map(str, output)))

#return a list of indices
def get_occurrences(pattern, text):
    res = []
    lenP = len(pattern)
    lenT = len(text)
    hp = getHash(pattern)
    ht = getHash(text[0 : lenP])

    # most significant coefficient
    msc = 1
    for i in range(lenP-1):
        msc = (msc * X) % P


    for i in range(1, lenT-lenP+2):
        if (hp == ht) and (pattern == text[i-1 : i-1 + lenP]):
            res.append(i-1)
        if i-1 + lenP < lenT:
            ht = (X*(ht - ord(text[i-1]) * msc) + ord(text[i-1 + lenP])) % P
            if ht < 0:
                ht += P

    return res

def getHash(s):
    res = 0
    l = len(s)
    for i in range(l):
        res += (ord(s[i]) * (X**(l-i-1))) % P
    return res % P



if __name__ == '__main__':
    print_occurrences(get_occurrences(*read_input()))
```

Comment: Stack Overflow specializes in not-working code. Optimization questions are better asked at [codereview.se]. (By the way, if your code is that much slower than expected, the problem appears to be in your implementation of the algorithm, and micro-optimization won't help.)